# angular 10 in html template array variable don't match type declaration

Tags: arrays, angular, templates, global

I am using a global variable and type defined as:

global.ts

```
export type ReservationCurrentPC = Array<{StartDateTime: string, EndDateTime: string, Who: string}>;
export class GlobalVariables {
    public static ReservationsCurrentPC: ReservationCurrentPC = [];
}
```

then imported it in component .ts

```
import { GlobalVariables , ReservationCurrentPC } from '../GlobalVariables';
```

then did a getter at component.ts for using it in its html template.

```
get GetReservationsMyPC(): ReservationCurrentPC { return GlobalVariables.ReservationsCurrentPC; };
```

then it executes a single push as:

```
case 'RSV':
    // stemp[i].Param1 = PCNameID.
    // stemp[i].Param2 = StartDate.
    // stemp[i].Param3 = EndDate.
    // stemp[i].Param4 = ReserveByAccountName.

GlobalVariables.ReservationsCurrentPC.push (stemp[i].Param2, stemp[i].Param3, stemp[i].Param4);
```

and then try to use it in the html template.

```
    <div *ngFor="let b of GetReservationsMyPC">
        <li>
            Desde [{{b.StartDateTime}}] hasta [{{b.EndDateTime}}] reservado para: {{b.Who}}
        </li>
        <button (click)="RemReserve(b.StartDateTime)">Remover esta reserva</button>          
    </div>
```

the problem is, the html loops 3 times with the variable 'b' , and it is not recognizing the type structure, like 3 fields per item, and like b.StartDateTime , b.EndDateTime, b.Who returns nothing, only if print just 'b' variable it will get the 3 strings pushed, as if it were a single plain array.

How to handle that structured variable properly at html template? I saw several examples but, using local-component variable, and that works, but I need to use this global variable because it is required to be filled from another component (which handled a map view where the user clicks, and the object clicked in the map triggers several events, and that is where is requested info from the API about the object clicked, and as response it returns the data for the push), so, it must be a global variable as it is handled in several components.

Comment: I see it in the JS debug console, the .push is broken, it is pushing as three main items, and not a single item with 3 fields member. Trying to understand how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

fixed:

```
GlobalVariables.ReservationsCurrentPC.push ({StartDateTime: stemp[i].Param2, EndDateTime: stemp[i].Param3, Who: stemp[i].Param4 });
```

What an adventure for me!.